# Bison: Optional tokens in a single rule

Tags: grammar, bison, flex-lexer

I'm using GNU Bison 2.4.2 to write a grammar for a new language I'm working on and I have a question.
When I specify a rule, let's say:

```
statement : T_CLASS T_IDENT  '{' T_CLASS_MEMBERS '}' {
           // create a node for the statement ...
}
```

If I have a variation on the rule, for instance

```
statement : T_CLASS T_IDENT T_EXTENDS T_IDENT_LIST  '{' T_CLASS_MEMBERS '}' {
           // create a node for the statement ...
}
```

Where (from flex scanner rules) :

```
"class"                     return T_CLASS;
"extends"                   return T_EXTENDS;
[a-zA-Z\_][a-zA-Z0-9\_]*    return T_IDENT;
```

(and T_IDENT_LIST is a rule for comma separated identifiers).

Is there any way to specify all of this only in one rule, setting somehow the "T_EXTENDS T_IDENT_LIST" as optional?
I've already tried with

```
 T_CLASS T_IDENT (T_EXTENDS T_IDENT_LIST)? '{' T_CLASS_MEMBERS '}' {
     // create a node for the statement ...
 }
```

But Bison gave me an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make a long story short, no. Bison only deals with LALR(1) grammars, which means it only uses one symbol of lookahead. What you need is something like this:

```
statement: T_CLASS T_IDENT extension_list '{' ...

extension_list: 
              | T_EXTENDS T_IDENT_LIST
              ;
```

There are other parser generators that work with more general grammars though. If memory serves, some of them support optional elements relatively directly like you're asking for.

Comment: That was the solution to write only one rule without the | :) Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with it being LALR(1), since both are LALR(1).  Its because the input syntax is BNF not EBNF.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Sorry, but wrong. The problem here is that as he wrote it, his parser would have to look ahead three symbols, across T_CLASS and T_IDENT to see whether the next symbol was a `{` or T_EXTENDS to see which `statement` variation to use. That's violating LALR(1). EBNF looks like a complete red-herring to me -- I see nothing that even resembles EBNF anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just split them using the choice (`|`) operator?

```
statement:
  T_CLASS T_IDENT T_EXTENDS T_IDENT_LIST  '{' T_CLASS_MEMBERS '}'
  | T_CLASS T_IDENT  '{' T_CLASS_MEMBERS '}'
```

I don't think you can do it just because this is a LALR(1) bottom-up parser, you would need something different like a LL(k) (ANTLR?) to do what you want to do..

Answer (score 0):

I think the most you can do is

```
statement : T_CLASS T_IDENT  '{' T_CLASS_MEMBERS '}'
    | T_CLASS T_IDENT T_EXTENDS T_IDENT_LIST  '{' T_CLASS_MEMBERS '}' {
}
```